# WorkManager wait for upload to finish before moving on to the next work request

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-workmanager

I'm using WorkManager in my Android app.
I've set a work request and in its doWork() method I'm uploading a file to Firebase Storage.
I want to chain this work request with another one, but I need the upload to finish (in order to get the download URL) before the next request starts (before I return Result.success).
How can I achieve this work?
Can I use LiveData inside the doWork() method?
How can I wait for the callback before I return the work's result?

*By the way, I'm trying to avoid redundant firebase calls, so the option for writing to the database, then update the database with the URL I get doesn't work for me.

Code:

```
class UploadWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters): Worker(context,workerParams)
{
    override fun doWork(): Result
    {
        //get input
        ...
        //store file in Firebase
        val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        val storageRef = storage.reference
        val fileRef = storageRef.child(filePath.toString())

        val uploadTask = fileRef.putBytes(file)
        var downloadFileUrl: String? = ""

        uploadTask.continueWithTask { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful)
            {
                task.exception?.let { throw it }
            }
            fileRef.downloadUrl
        }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful)
            {
                //this is what I want to save before the return of doWork()
                downloadFileUrl = task.result.toString()
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle failures
                Log.d("fb", "fail")
            }
        }

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

Comment: have you read the chaining docs? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work

Comment: yes, I understand how to implement the chaining part, the question is about waiting for a callback before proceeding

Comment: you can use `com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(task)` which removes the callbacks and treats as a synchronous call

Comment: Can you please be more specific or give an example?

Answer (score 1):

Just take your `uploadTask` and use the `Tasks.await()`

I dont know the exact syntax but its something like this

```
override fun doWork(): Result{
    .....
    val uploadTask = fileRef.putBytes(file)
    val taskResult = Tasks.await(uploadTask) 
    downloadFileUrl = taskResult.result.toString()
    ....
    return Result.success()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else faces the same issue later on, what you need to use is the storage reference, not the upload task

```
override fun doWork(): Result{
    .....
    val downloadUriTask = Tasks.await(imageRef.downloadUrl)
    val url = downloadUriTask.toString()
    ....
    return Result.success()
}
```